# Xcode 3.2 Missing Class Actions / Outlets?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, macos, osx-snow-leopard

Where are the Class Action and Class Outlets in Xcode 3.2? They aren't showing up in the Inspector like they used to.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Got it.

Anyone else that was wondering, those options were moved into the Library window, under classes. If you pick the specific class, you will see the action and outlet tab on the bottom.

Answer (score 3):

Below are some additional instructions based on ACBurk's answer:

1. Select the class you wish to inspect from MainWindow.xib (or any under XIB you're editing).
2. Open Identity Inspector (Apple Key + 4).
3. In the Class Identity section, click the right arrow image beside the class name.
4. That should load up Library window for the selected class.
5. Switch to the appropriate tab (at the bottom of the Library window) for Outlets and Actions.

Answer (score 1):

I think once you create the object in your interface, it shows up in the classes list in the Library dialog.  You can then add the Outlets and Actions on the object from that window.